# Basic proof involving invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain the importance of invariant subspace. I am looking at a proof for the existence of an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of a nxn  symmetric matrix $A$.

It states that $A$ has some eigenvector $v_1, Av_1 = \lambda v_1$ Assume $\|v_1\| = 1$
Then to look at $v_1 ^{\perp}$. 
It shows why $v_1 ^{\perp}$ is $A$ invariant.
Using induction since $v_1 ^{\perp}$ has dimension $n-1$, we have an orthonormal basis of V of eigenvectors: $v_2, v_3, \ldots, v_n$ for A in $v_1 ^{\perp}$. Therefore $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots, v_n$ is an orthonormal basis for V and all basis vectors are eigenvectors for $A$. $\square$

What I don't understand is why we needed $v_1 ^{\perp}$ to be $A$ invariant. If someone can help out, that would be amazing

Comment: Because you need it to be invariant to be able to restrict the action of $A$ to an endomorphism of that space (i.e have a map $L_A\big|_{v_1^\bot}:v_1^\bot\hookrightarrow v_1^\bot$) , and thus apply the induction step. Else you couldn't do that :)

Comment: @b00nheT so are you saying that because $v_1^{\perp}$ is A invariant, A must be symmetric on  $v_1^{\perp}$?

Comment: $A$ is always symmetric, indipendently from the space it acts on as endomorphismus via left multiplication. Thus what you need is exactly this last space to let $A$ act on (of lower dimension), which you find by the above reasoning with the invariance of the orthogonal complement. Because there by the induction step, you CAN find such a basis.

So ask yourself: what does really state the induction argument?

Answer (score 1):

The Spectral Theorem is given by induction over the dimension $n$ of the space $E$.

The following result is important:

Let $A: E \to  E$ be self-adjoint, if subspace $F \subset E$ that is A invariant, then its orthogonal complement $F^{\perp}$ is also A invariant.

The above result comes from the fact that $F^{\perp}$  invariant by the adjoint operator $A^* : E \to E$. In fact,

$$u \in F, v \in F^{\perp} \implies Au \in F \implies \langle u , A^*v \rangle = \langle Au , v \rangle = 0 \implies A^*v \in F^{\perp}$$

Thus $F^{\perp}$ is $A^*$ invariant  .

With this in mind, on the induction step we find a unitary eingenvector $u_n$ then its $A$ invariant subspace $F \subset E$ has dimension $1$. By the result above $F^{\perp}$ is also $A$ invariant and with dimension $n -1$. From here you may apply the induction hypothesis on $F^{\perp}$.

Comment: This is obviously correct, yet I would furthermore clarify the difference between the Matrix $A$ as stillstanding object, and its role as *linear selfadjoint operator* while considering its action al left multiplication on the base vector space. Considering that we are dealing with basic linear algebra

Comment: @b00nheT Do you mean to make clear that for each selfadjoint operator there exists a matrix $A$ symmetric?

Comment: (I am definitely not the downvoter)
anyway, no: I am not sure the user will fully understand you more general result due to the choice of different terminology, and the difficulty of the double role of a matrix as object and operator. But that can be left to him after all :)

Comment: I as well did not downvote. I found yours and @b00n het 's reply to be very helpful. Thanks alot

Comment: @lllll I'm glad I could help!